# 2 Style Qs: Any reason to not reuse tags? Switch statement curly-braces?

Tags: xcode, authentication, tags, styles, reusability

Hey there Stack Overflow! Feel free to skip the code if you understand my question without it; It's more or less just to provide some code for learners that stumble across this thread.

1) Is it of poor style to reuse tags?

2) For switch statements, is it good practice to always use curly-braces for each case? I do so because I'm well aware of the old ARC changes leading to "switch case is in protected scope" errors that occur when you assign a variable within the case's block. I ask for the same reason as #1: I'm looking to tighten up my code without developing bad style habits.

I'm just whipping up this example to cover both, so excuse typos/etc.:

Login.m

```
-(void)irrelevantSignInMethod
{
    //Failed login
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"Log in failed" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Try Again", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert setTag:1];
    ...
    //Confirmed login
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sweet!" message:@"You've logged in!" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Sweet!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:signInUsername.text forKey:@"username"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [alert setTag:2];
}

-(void)irrelevantSignUpThenInMethod
{
    ....
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sweet!" message:@"You've registered and logged in!" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Sweet!" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [alert setTag:3];
    //Just here to remind code-borrowers to store username somewhere
    [defaults setObject:signInUsername.text forKey:@"username"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    //Here's where the question lies; is there any reason to not tweak to [alert setTag:2], shaving an if statement in the clickButtonAtIndex method?
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Try Again"]))
            {
                //I always add an alert with "Try Again" in case the log in failed
                UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
                UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
                signInUsername.text = username.text;
                signInPassword.text = password.text;
                [self attemptSignIn];
                break;
            }
        }
    case 2:
        {
            [self loggedIn];
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            //Here's where question #1 lies; is there any reason to not just assign both alerts the same tag (2) earlier and not need a 3rd case?
            [self loggedIn];
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            //Forgot password scenario. Too lazy to write how I do this out - but will answer if anyone PMs me - those borrowing this code should be prepared for this situation!
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I realize the code probably wasn't necessary - but who knows, someone may benefit from seeing a basic login structure. If I wasn't clear earlier, I'll elaborate on my questions: can I go ahead and assign tag 2 twice and simplify the clickedButtonAtIndex method? I'm a CS major and covered this several semesters back, so I don't recall if there was any clarification. I doubt a technical reason to distinguish exists, and I'm all about concise code, but I don't want to start getting in a habit of breaking a "that's the classic way" formality going forward; especially as I'm graded on style and work with others on larger projects. I know it's a minute question, but I find myself wondering how most people go about this, and would love a dialogue with your expertise. As far as the switch brackets question: I know this can be deemed as preference (some of you code as "concise as possible" while others code as "consistent as possible") ... I'm just curious what the seasoned vets think should be the 'status quo.'

3) I know this is poor (edit: awful) etiquette, but I would love at least 1 'vote' so I am eligible to start 'voting up' because I use knowledge from other threads countless times every day, and as a lurker of over half a decade, I feel it's time to start rewarding the helpful with oh-so-valuable internet points.

Thanks for your time Stack Overflow. You truly are the best for understanding concepts, discovering solutions, and developing developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you reuse the tags, I **do not** think you can identify the which alert view is which in clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method.

Also there might be issues when you use viewWithTag function in a view that contains subviews with the same tag.

And for me, it will be better to define some const for the tags so that it is easier for you to look through your codes, for example 3 set as IRRELEVANT_SIGN_UP_ALERT_TAG. Then in your code you can just use the IRRELEVANT_SIGN_UP_ALERT_TAG instead of 3, which is easier to understand instead of looking through the code guessing what is 3 for. When there is a need to change the tag, you do not need to change the occurrences of 3 one by one too.

Curly braces are a good idea for switch statement, for example you can create a variable inside the switch statement with them: [How do I create a variable inside a switch statement for a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902568/how-do-i-create-a-variable-inside-a-switch-statement-for-a-uitableview)